# How to test localized web application?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, localization, internationalization

I work out of New Zealand developing a web application for some Romanian clients.  The application should default to ro-RO when viewed by a client using a Romanian machine and en-GB for pretty much everyone else at this stage. Problem is ALL machines I have used to test this are defaulting to en-US. That is, machines on Windows Azure European data centers, local machines here in NZ  and various machine in Romania which I access via RDP.

So i use this code in a controller to set language based on user defaults:

```
 public static void OnBeginExecuteCore(Controller controller)
        {
            if (controller.RouteData.Values[Constants.ROUTE_PARAMNAME_LANG] != null &&
                !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(controller.RouteData.Values[Constants.ROUTE_PARAMNAME_LANG].ToString()))
            {
                // set the culture from the route data (url)
                var lang = controller.RouteData.Values[Constants.ROUTE_PARAMNAME_LANG].ToString();
                Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture(lang);
            }
            else
            {
                // load the culture info from the cookie
                var cookie = controller.HttpContext.Request.Cookies[Constants.COOKIE_NAME];
                var langHeader = string.Empty;
                if (cookie != null)
                {
                    // set the culture by the cookie content
                    langHeader = cookie.Value;
                    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture(langHeader);
                }
                else
                {
                    // set the culture by the location if not specified
                    langHeader = controller.HttpContext.Request.UserLanguages[0];
                    if (langHeader.ToLower() == "en-us") langHeader = "en-GB";
                    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture(langHeader);
                }
                // set the lang value into route data
                controller.RouteData.Values[Constants.ROUTE_PARAMNAME_LANG] = langHeader;
            }

            // save the location into cookie
            HttpCookie cultCookie;
            cultCookie = new HttpCookie(Constants.COOKIE_NAME, Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture.Name)
            {
                Expires = DateTime.Now.AddYears(1)
            };
            controller.HttpContext.Response.SetCookie(cultCookie);
        }
```

where

```
langHeader = controller.HttpContext.Request.UserLanguages[0];
```

is always en-US. There are in fact 3 entries in this collection however:

[image]

but ro is clearly not weighted correctly. This is the same across all machines in all locales.

Globalization in web config is set to auto:

```
 <globalization requestEncoding="utf-8"
               culture="auto"
               uiCulture="auto"
```

And regional windows settings are as follows:

[image]

[image]

Browser:

[image]
How can I make this work?

**ANSWER**

As per Martins answer in comments. Problem was that I had this in *apparently* all settings the world over.

[image]

when what I really wanted was this *in Chrome*... will get to the other browsers soon.

[image]

Comment: Have you actually updated the browsers you're using to test this to specify `ro` as the preferred language?  You shouldn't need to update the whole OS to test this.

Comment: Using chrome in Romainian yes. Please see update as "proof".

Comment: Setting the browser's UI language doesn't *necessarily* mean it's sending the same language to servers.   Have you checked the Chrome Advanced options for the languages to send to servers?  You should be able to "pretend" to be Romanian while having Chrome running in English.

Comment: ah-hah - brilliant. That's the answer if you want to scribe it up.  Otherwise I can delete this post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ensure that your browser of choice (Internet Explorer, Chrome, Firefox, Safari etc.) has been set up to specify `ro` as the first language in the User Languages sent over HTTP to the server.

Updating the Windows and/or browser's UI language won't *necessarily* cause a non-English language ISO code to be sent to the server, which means that you'd just get English returned.

In Firefox, for example, this setting can be found under Options->Content->Languages->Choose.

Comment: +1. In IE the option is Internet Options -> Languages -> Language Preference. You can add multiple languages with different order.